# How to chain checks in java

Tags: java, refactoring, chaining

Consider a class like the following

```
public class MyClass {

    private Integer myField;
    private Result result;
    // more global variables

    public MyResult check(Integer myParameter) {
        init(myParameter);

        if (myField < 0) {
            result.setErrorMessage("My error message");
            return result;
        }

        // a lot more 'checks' like above where something may be written
        // to the error message and the result gets returned.
    }

    private void init(Integer myParameter) {
        result = new Result();
        result.setExistsAnnouncement(/*search a certain object via crudService with myParameter*/);
        // initialize other global variables including myField
    }

}
```

The problem is that the `check` method above is way too long and has many  `return` statements. I thought of some refactorings but am still unsure what to do. I was thinking about something like a chain-pattern. I would then implement several checker-classes who either call the next checker in the chain or return `result` with a corresponding `errorMessage`.

But then I had an even better idea (at least I think so): Why not behave like java 8? I thought of using something like `Try`-`Success`-`Failure`-Pattern. But I have no clue how to realize this. I am thinking of something like:

```
entrancePoint.check(firstChecker)
    .check(secondChecker)
    .check // and so on
```

The idea would be: When `check` fails, it would behave like `Optional.map()` and return something like an `Optional.EMPTY` (or in this context something like a `Failure`). When `check` is successful it should go on and do the next check (return a `Success`).

Do you have any experience in doing something like this?

Comment: I have done the same thing before, but without chaining. The way I did it, was 1.) Create an interface `Checkable`, which contains a method `check()` that needs to throw some `CheckFailedException`,  and a few concrete implementations of this interface. 2.) Create a `List<Checkable>` variable in `MyClass` and the `check()` in `MyClass` iterates over each element of checkable and invokes `check()` on it. 3.) Use the constructor or setter method to initialize the list of checks to be performed (I was using spring, so I made it that way).

Comment: Yes, this might work. But I think that there are better solutions out there. At the moment I am still trying to do this with Try-Failure-Success-Pattern like done here: https://dzone.com/articles/whats-wrong-java-8-part-iv. The difference is: In the link they did it for exceptions... I am using this Try-Success-Failure-Implementations btw: https://gist.github.com/mariofusco/8287951

Comment: Can you use Hibernate Validator, if you know the constraints at compile time? http://hibernate.org/validator/

Comment: @aepure: The checks not only have to do with database related things.

Comment: @Chris311 I like your implementation. In fact, I might use that in my application as well. What I thought, that you want to chain-up checks, right? You could try doing something like `Try<Checkable>`, but I am afraid that will create more overheads and confusion or clutter up things the worst-case-scenario...

Comment: @Chris311 - I don't understand your comment. Hibernate Validator implements the JSR 303 Bean Validation Standard. It's just one of the implementations. How is the JSR 303 standard tied to "database related things"? https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303

Comment: @aepure: Ok, I'll give you another answer: Yes, I can use Hibernate Validator. You can provide an answer, if you think it is a solution to my problem.

Comment: @Chris311 I think I have found a solution to your problem. I am making a Gist right now. Expect my answer very soon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When we think about validation, it is generally a Composite pattern. It broadly is depicted as:

**If THIS is valid, then do SOMETHING**.

And as you are imposing, you want to chain up multiple checkers in a chain to perform validation in their area, you can implement a **Chain of Responsibility** pattern.

Consider this:

You can have a `Result` Object, that can contain a message about failure as well as simple true/false.

You can have a `Validator` Object, that does whatever validation is required and returns an instance of `Result`.

```
public interface Result {  
    public boolean isOk();
    public String getMessage();
}

// We make it genric so that we can use it to validate
// any type of Object that we want.
public interface Validator<T> {
    public Result validate(T value);
}
```

Now when you say that you want to validate 'X' using multiple checkers, you're imposing a *Validation Rule* that is nothing but a collection of `Validator` objects while being an instance of `Validator` itself. That being said, you can no more use the `Result` object to check the validation result of your rule. You will need a composite `Result` object that can keep the results as `{Validator=Result}`. Doesn't it look like an implementation of `HashMap<Validator, Result>`? Yes, because it is.

Now you can implement your `Rule` and `CompositeResult` as:

```
public class Rule extends ArrayList<Validator> implements Validator {

    public Rule(Validator<?> ... chain) {
        addAll(Arrays.asList(chain));
    }

    public Object validate(Object target) {
        CompositeResult result = new CompositeResult(size());
        for (Validator rule : this) {
            Result tempResult = rule.validate(value);
            if (!tempResult.isOk())
                result.put(rule, tempResult);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class CompositeResult extends HashMap<Validator, Result> implements
        Result {

    private Integer appliedCount;

    public CompositeResult(Integer appliedCount) {
        this.appliedCount = appliedCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOk() {
        boolean isOk = true;
        for (Result r : values()) {
            isOk = r.isOk();
            if (!isOk)
                break;
        }
        return isOk;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return toString();
    }

    public Integer failCount() {
        return size();
    }

    public Integer passCount() {
        return appliedCount - size();
    }

}
```

And that's it! Now, to implement your checkers:

```
public class Checker1 implements Validator<Integer> {
    /* Implementation */
}

public class CheckerN implements Validator<Integer> {
    /* Implementation */
}
```

And it's time to do the validation:

```
Validator<Integer> checkingRule = new Rule(new Checker1(), new CheckerN());
CompositeResult result = checkingRule.validate(yourParameter);
if (result.isOk()) 
    System.out.println("All validations passed");
else
    System.out.println(result.getFailedCount() + " validations failed");
```

Easy and neat.

I have uploaded an [example in my public repo](https://github.com/JExaples/quicklooks/tree/master/Chain-of-Responsibility) for you to play around.

Comment: Very nice solution! There is only one difference: All of your validators are executed, while I wanted to return after the first check fails. But one can easy adapt your `validate` to meet my requirements.

Comment: @Chris311 you're right. You could throw an exception in case any of the components of the Rule fail, but I was too lazy to implement that.

Comment: I would rather use a `break` then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) (or another implementation of the [JSR 303/349/380](http://beanvalidation.org/specification/) Bean Validation standards).

Example user class that throws an exception when being instantiated with invalid arguments. You can check all the built in constraints [in the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bean-constraints.html#validator-defineconstraints-spec)

```
    public final class User {

      @NotNull
      private final String username;

      @NotNull
      private final String firstName;

      @NotNull
      private final String lastName;

      public User(String username, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.username = username;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

        MyValidator.validate(this);
      }
      // public getters omitted
    }
```

And the validator class:

```
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;

public final class MyValidator {

    public static void validate(Object object) {

      ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
      Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

      Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate( object );

      if (!constraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
          ConstraintViolation<Object> firstViolation = constraintViolations.iterator().next();

          throw new InvalidParameterException("not valid "
          + object.getClass()
          + " failed property ' " + firstViolation.getPropertyPath() + " ' "
          + " failure message ' " + firstViolation.getMessage() + " ' ");
      }
    }
}
```

And message:

> java.security.InvalidParameterException: not valid class
>   com.foo.bar.User failed property ' firstName '  failure message ' may not be null '

Don't forget to include [the dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator) in your pom.xml (if you use Maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```