# Dinamically setting the validity of the state consistency of an object in relation of the action we have to perform

Tags: java, validation, design-patterns, action, builder

I have searched very hard on google on every possible discussion forum about this topic but I can't seem to find anything that meets my needs. I try to explain what I want to obtain: basically I want to use something similar to the builder pattern to validate the state of an object in creation phase because this allows me to centralize the validation logic in an elegant way and it is readable and easy to maintain by a developer. For example such a code:

```
Person person = new PersonBuilder()
                    .id(1)                     //mandatory
                    .name("John")              //mandatory
                    .surname("Smith")          //mandatory
                    .age(36)                   //mandatory
                    .hobbies("Playing tennis") //optional
                    .build();
```

for me is very elegant and readable and it is perfect because everytime that I want to use an object of the `Person` class I can provide only valid state of object before stepping through the next phases.

But to think about it this validation rules are good only for an object for which I want to perform an insert or update because the validator checks that all mandatory fields are setted otherwise throws back an `IllegalStateExcpetion`.
What if I want to perform a research of the person by any of the available attributes? I mean when I search for an object I don't have to specific all the mandatory fields. I could also specify just the surname or just one of the other available fields.

Could it be acceptable to add a `buildForSearch` method into the builder with different criteria of validation?

I know that maybe is conceptually wrong to differentiate the entity behaviour of validation basing on the actions but do you know if there is a pattern to accomplish this, maintaining the advantages of the builder pattern?

Comment: UPDATE: I forgot to specify that I want to use pure java not frameworks.

Comment: I would have done something like this: - Create a class `PersonPool` which may extend some sort of collection or use a delegate object to store all the persons ever created. - Create an enum `SearchOption` that could list all the possibilities such as search by object, search by age, etc. - Create a method like `List<Person> search(SearchOption, Object)` that searches for an object(s) in the pool and then returns a list or empty collection as the search result... Maybe I am not getting your exact requirement, but I could have done it this way.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you very much for your reply. I try to better explain my issue: let's say we have the object person which attribute age is a mandatory integer and it can only have values between 1 and 100. If we have to insert/update this object into a db, my validation will have to check that age has been setted and that the range is correct. But if I want to make a research on the person I don't have to set mandatorly the age but if I set it it must respect the range between 1 and 100.

Comment: So, in case of research, I would like to re-use just the part of logic validation that I use in case of insert or update of the person that checks the range validity but I don't want the attribute is considered mandatory. I don't want to put my validation logic in an ActionForm or in an Action or things like that.

Comment: I like the way you validate and build the object. Alternatively, to chain up validations while keeping all the validation logic decoupled, you can refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226111/how-to-chain-checks-in-java/43276146#43276146). Then you can always validate and search, or validate and update while keeping the logic neat.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for your suggestion. I have been study your solution and it seems very clean to me. Anyway what I want to obtain is a coupled validation with the object creation. That's why I was thinking of a builder. The only problem is that the builder I have in mind would have more than one  build method to act differently on the action I want to perform (if insert/update use a build method, if search use another build method into the same builder) so I don't know if it would be a clean solution or if it would violate the pattern principles.

Comment: If it is not a right solution I would like to know if there is a pattern or a solution that allows having validation into the object that have different rules on different actions I have to perform on that object.

Comment: Then, in this case, you could use a mix of the builder pattern that you are using, with a strategy or a factory pattern.

Comment: Ok I will try. Thank you Jay for your reply you've been very kind.